# what is ranks do in Singular value decomposition, if rank = k, others than k first singular values set to 0 or gone?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd

hi lets assume we have matrix A with 4 rows x 3 columns, when we input to svd it become:

> U = 4x4 , S = 4x3 and VT = 3x3.

after that i specify that rank **k=2** so what exactly happen to the **other** than the first k ranks? is it set to zero or completely gone like

> U = 4x2 S=2x2 and VT = 2x3?

both cases resulting the same rows and columns, right? which is 4x3, but does it affect the value of the reduced matrix?

Comment: It may be obvious,  but in the presence of numerical rounding errors, one expects some spurious nonzero singular values to appear in the decomposition.  I'm guessing that these are not of concern to you, but if they are, reply to this or edit the body of the Question, and I'll write up something about "rank revealing SVD".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, $A = USV^T$, where 
$$U = [u_1 \ u_2 \ u_3 \ u_4]$$
$$V = [v_1 \ v_2 \ v_3]$$
where $u_i$ is the $i^{th}$ column of $U$. (Same for $V$). Now, $S$ is a diagonal rectangular containing the Singular values of $A$, i.e.
$$S = \begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \sigma_2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \sigma_3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Notice that the number of non-zero singular values indicates the rank of $A$, hence if you have rank$A$ = 2, then (assuming the singular values are sorted $\sigma_1 \geq \sigma_2 \geq \sigma_3$), we will have $\sigma_3 = 0$
Hence
$$S = \begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \sigma_2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$
Hence
$$A = USV^T = \sigma_1 u_1v_1^T + \sigma_2 u_2v_2^T = \bar{U}\bar{S}\bar{V}^T$$, where
$$\bar{U} = [u_1 \ u_2] \in \mathbb{R}^{4\times2}$$
$$\bar{V} = [v_1 \ v_2 ] \in \mathbb{R}^{3\times2} $$
and 
$$\bar{S} = \begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_1 & 0 \\
0 & \sigma_2 \\
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^{2\times2}$$

Comment: ahh i see, now i get it. thank youu